# Why desktop entry files for scripts are ignored without "sh"?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I have a simple desktop entry file for showing the script icon in the dock:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=digi2kvm
Comment=Backup NB > KVM
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Yaru/256x256/apps/backups-app.png
Exec=/home/honza/.skripty/mybackup.sh
```

The script consists of an rsync command accompanied with zenity showing the overall status of the process. Strange is it works perfectly on one Ubuntu 19.04 installation but not on the other. On the other the entry disappears from the dock until I put **sh** before the Exec path. But with **sh** the script does not work as expected, it omits the zenity part, which is quite important for me. It apparently runs in a child shell but this is not what I need.

Why is gnome so sensitive to this and how to solve this on the second machine?

**important**

There is no problem with the script, it works as expected (and is executable), the problem is really in the entry file and its disappearance from the dock. I tried to put it in both `.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications` but the result is still the same. I also tried to use the short script simply as a pipe directly in the entry file (Exec=rsync...) but it did not work at all.

1. `Exec=/home/honza/.skripty/mybackup.sh` works on one machine, icon in the dock as expected. On the second machine the icon disappears.
2. `Exec=sh /home/honza/.skripty/mybackup.sh` does not work but the icon reappears in the dock (on the second machine).

Comment: That surely sounds strange! Consider [edit]ing your question and add (the core of) the script if possible.

Comment: Is the script executable? does it start with `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`?